# Undefined method 'visit' for #<Class:XYZ> (NoMethodError) [rspec]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm getting the following error when I try to run an rspec test:

```
/srv/offerme/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:13: undefined method `visit' for #<Class:0xb3436684> (NoMethodError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
from /srv/offerme/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:12
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
from /srv/offerme/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:3
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `autorun'
from /usr/local/bin/rspec:19
```

The file I get this error in looks like this (spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb) :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do
include Capybara::DSL
  describe "GET /static_pages" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
      get static_pages_index_path
      response.status.should be(200)
    end 
  end 
  describe "Home page" do
    visit 'static_pages/home'
    page.should have_content('OfferMe')
  end 

end
```

My spec_helper.rb file looks like this:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
module ::RSpec::Core
class ExampleGroup
include Capybara::DSL
include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
end
end
```

And, finally, my Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.1'
gem 'libv8'
gem 'webrat'
```

I have seen this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/360) and have tried some of the workarounds as well as looked at some other StackOverflow questions pertaining to the similar issue (that's why some of the code looks redundant/hacky). However, none of them have worked yet. Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE:

The problem is that you're calling `visit` outside of an `it` block, here:

```
describe "Home page" do
  visit 'static_pages/home'
  page.should have_content('OfferMe')
end
```

Wrap those middle lines in an `it` block:

```
describe "Home page" do
  it "has a homepage" do
    visit 'static_pages/home'
    page.should have_content('OfferMe')
  end
end
```

That should work.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I could be wrong, but I believe you have to include capybara in both the test and development sections of your Gemfile.

Try changing that section of your Gemfile to this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

Comment: Hmm... well, one other thing I noticed was that you don't require 'capybara/rails' in `spec_helper.rb`. On the [capybara github page](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/) it specifies that you should have this if you're using capybara for a rails project. Try adding that and see if it works.

Comment: That did not work either. Does the order of the require statements matter?

Comment: Hmm... no, that shouldn't matter. I don't see anything else that could be causing it.

Comment: Oh wait, I see it. You have `visit` outside of an `it` block, which won't work. You need to wrap it in an `it` block.

Comment: You're welcome! I've had that problem before, so when I saw it I immediately knew it was the cause.

Comment: ok, but what if I have visit in some spec helper. like for login user ?

Comment: as long as you call that helper inside an `it` block, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post. I have had the same issue. I thought I share my solution. 
In my Gemfile I have had

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

And the `visit` was in the right spot however I was getting the same error. so this is what I did. I ran the update on the Gem and all are good now.

`bundle update capybara`

Hope this help someone.