# undefined method `visit' when using RSpec and Capybara in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I can't get capybara working with rspec. It gives me this error:

```
undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x16529f8 @example=nil>
```

I know there are lots of posts about this but non of the solutions are working for me. Most of them involve the specs not being in /spec/features - which mine is in.

First the error:

```rb
$bundle exec rspec spec
F

Failures:

  1) security signs users in
     Failure/Error: visit "/sessions/new"
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x16529f8 @example=nil>
     # ./spec/features/security_spec.rb:4:in `(root)'

 Finished in 0.006 seconds
 1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/security_spec.rb:3 # security signs users in
```

I think its important to note that at first I was using the URL Helper 'new_sessions_path' and it kept giving me an error `undefined local variable or method 'new_sessions_path'`. I know it is valid because:

```rb
$ rake routes
logout_sessions GET    /sessions/logout(.:format) sessions#logout
       sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)        sessions#create
   new_sessions GET    /sessions/new(.:format)    sessions#new
      contracts POST   /contracts(.:format)       contracts#create
  new_contracts GET    /contracts/new(.:format)   contracts#new
 edit_contracts GET    /contracts/edit(.:format)  contracts#edit
                GET    /contracts(.:format)       contracts#show
                PUT    /contracts(.:format)       contracts#update
                DELETE /contracts(.:format)       contracts#destroy
           root        /                          contracts#index
```

My Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'execjs'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 1.4.1'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'therubyrhino'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'nokogiri'

group :development do
  gem 'warbler'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'
end
```

spec_helper.rb inside of my_app/spec:

```rb
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Capybara integration
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
  # Include path helpers
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

my_app/spec/features/security_spec.rb:

```rb
describe "security", :type => :feature do
  it "signs users in" do
    visit "/sessions/new"
    fill_in "username", :with => "user"
    fill_in "password", :with => "pass"
    click_button "Sign In"

    page.should have_content('Login Successful')
  end
end
```

I've tried defining the test above both with and without `:type => :feature`. It makes no difference either way. Any ideas what I should try next?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capybara: undefined method 'visit'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059854/capybara-undefined-method-visit)

Comment: @mlt in the first paragraph I said:

"I know there are lots of posts about this but non of the solutions are working for me. Most of them involve the specs not being in /spec/features - which mine is in."

This paragraph is specifically referencing the question you link to. This question not only has higher votes, but also comes with a solution - which is different than the highest voted answer (not solution) posted on your linked question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Adding `require 'rails_helper'` at the top of my feature ended up fixing my problem:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe "security", :type => :feature do

  it "signs users in" do
    visit new_sessions_path
    fill_in "username", :with => "user"
    fill_in "password", :with => "pass"
    click_button "Sign In"

    page.should have_content('Login Successful')
  end
end
```

This seems odd to me since every example I've seen for rspec and capybara didn't have that require, but oh well. Problem solved.

## Original Answer (older versions of rspec)

`require 'spec_helper'` is used by older versions of RSpec. The better answer would be `require 'rails_helper'`.

Comment: You should put the update part in the top of your post.

Comment: It is really bad manner to accept ones own answer, even though Kocur4d's answer is more precise (and forgetting to include the rails_helper.rb would not be the more common problem). You should change the accepted answer, as without the configuration change done before including it, you would still have the same error.

Answer (score 213):

Try to add:

```
  config.include Capybara::DSL
```

to your config block.

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
  # Include path helpers
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  config.include Capybara::DSL

end
```

Comment: Nope, exact same issue, no apparent change

Comment: This worked for me -- thanks a ton. I didn't need to do this though in my other projects. What circumstances would make this necessary in one project, but not another? Also, what exactly is this doing?

Comment: My file already had the require 'spec_helper' that was checked asthe answer to this problem, but this worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't work for me: I get an error message that `Capybara` is an undefined constant. My Cucumber tests are using Capybara just fine.

Answer (score 37):

Since Capybara 2.0 one has to use folder spec/features Capybara commands don't work in folder spec/requests anymore.

Comment: As my question states, my capybara test **was** already located under `spec/features`. But that is a valid point for other people who might be having issues.

Comment: I find it helpful to create the directory `mkdir spec/features` and create a symbolic link `ln -s spec/features spec/requests`. This way any generated tests will be placed in the features directory.

Comment: Thanks @ThillaiNarayanan, this was my issue following an older setup guide, but on a more recent Capybara version

Comment: this happens because of the setting `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` inside of your Rspec configure. see https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/main/lib/rspec/rails/configuration.rb#L7

Answer (score 6):

Try performing all your setup in a `before` block:

**spec/features/security_spec.rb**

```
describe "security" do
  before do
    visit "/sessions/new"
    fill_in "username", :with => "user"
    fill_in "password", :with => "pass"
    click_button "Sign In"
  end

  it "signs users in" do
    page.should have_content('Login Successful')
  end
end
```

Comment: This is actually a common **cause** of the error. The `visit` function is only available within a `it` block. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11911471/912563)

Comment: Not true -- code in a `before` block runs in the example context, so `visit` will work there as well as in an `it` block.

Comment: @user912563, ultimately, since you solved your own problem, my answer just really becomes a style suggestion more than anything else (set up code in `before` blocks is how I write my specs, and they work without error ;-) ), so I think it's fair to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks @zetetic and @Paul-Firavanti - I did not know `before` was still inside the `it` context. Using this will make my other tests that require login much cleaner

Comment: This helped me because I'm a noob and didn't have test wrapped in it "" do ... end.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem,

Adding require 'rails_helper' at the top of my feature ended up fixing my problem:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Products", type: :request do
 describe "GET /products" do
 it "display tasks" do
  Product.create!(:name => "samsung")
  visit products_path
  page.should have_content("samsung")
  #expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
  end
 end
end
```

And add the 'config.include Capybara::DSL' in rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

 config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

 config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

 config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

 config.include Capybara::DSL

end
```

Comment: Adding that Config line worked for me. It's strange because I was getting the error in one of my spec files but not in another spec file, and both called the same capy methods (and both required rails_helper)

Comment: adding only config.include Capybara::DSL inside rails_helper.rb would resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the upgrading issue which you would run into when ugprading from an older Rails app with `require 'spec_helper.rb'` instead of `require 'rails_helper.rb'`, this happens for 3 known reasons:

**1. Your spec isn't of type "feature"**
which means Capybara doesn't know how to run it using Javascript or a browser. You want to do one of two things: 1) Typically, you want `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` set in your RSpec.configure and that will mean that what's in the features folder will be a feature.

if you have something non-standard, you can add `type: :feature` to the spec describe block to turn that spec in a feature, but typically it's easier just to put  them into the /features folder and let the infer setting do its job.

**2. You accidentally put the `visit` outside of the it block**

The visit must be within the it, which is within the describe. Be sure not to put the visit directly within the describe.

**3. Some other kernal panic you can't see has caused Capy to shut down the spec.**

This is a nasty one to diagnose but I have seen it. It means that Capy didn't actually parse this file correctly, and so somehow isn't in the right scope when it gets to the visit block. Carefully pick apart your Capy spec to figure out where you introduced it.

I induced the kernal panic today but have a `let` block be called `page` (whoops). `page` appears to be a reserved word for Rspec or Capy here, and it causes the kernal panic, thus leading to the spec not to parse thus leading to the `visit` method not being found.

in my case, it was simply changing this:

```
let(:page) {Page.new()}
```

to

```
let(:content_page) {Page.new()}
```

Notice that the word `page` is not reserved by Rails, and works fine as a database name and also a model name, but the specific construction of using `page` here as the let variable name seemed to cause Capy to get kind of crappy.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons might be if you defined `page` variable using `let`:

```rb
RSpec.describe "something" do
  let(:page) { some_page }

  it do
    visit "/"
  end
end
```

Results in the following error:

```
  1) something
     Failure/Error: visit "/"

     NameError:
       undefined method `visit' for class `#<Class:0x00007ffca6221898>'
       Did you mean?  visible
```

To fix it, rename `page` variable.