# undefined method `visit` rspec/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am following Michael Hartls tutorial on `rspec` and I am getting this error

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb 
F

Failures:

  1) Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit '/static_pages/home'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::StaticPages::HomePage:0x007fdddbdf6a90>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00052 seconds (files took 0.1562 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:5 # Static pages Home page should have the content 'Sample App'
```

for the rspec test.

```
require 'spec_helper' 

describe "Static pages" do
    describe "Home page" do
        it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do 
            visit '/static_pages/home'
            page.should have_content('Sample App')
        end 
    end
end
```

I don't believe that the reason I am getting this error is the test case is failing but rather this:

```
NoMethodError:
           undefined method `visit' for #<RSpec:....
```

I am not sure why there is an undefined method `visit`

Comment: what is in your `spec_helper` file?

Comment: Try moving your spec into the **spec/features/** directory if you're using Capybara >= 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just missed:

```
config.include Capybara::DSL
```

also you could look to the same qestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148585/undefined-method-visit-when-using-rspec-and-capybara-in-rails)